# Docker random ports & AWS Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, port, amazon-elb, docker-swarm

I'm trying to host a Docker Swarm cluster on AWS via (on CoreOS machines) which will run multiple apps and load balancing for each app. Is there a way to group apps from random ports to an Elastic Load Balancer(ELB)? When I try it manually, ELB only stitch containers that run on a specific port. Instead I'm want a mesh-style reverse proxy for ELB.

Comment: this is a massive shortcoming of AWS with Docker- it doesn't support random ports to ELB, and fixed ports don't distribute well.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue: AWS ELB can get the dynamic ports from ECS dockers. if you set the host port to 0 and Container port to what you want. 

But then you will run into another massive shortcoming: The ELB security group is not updated to let the traffic through the dynamic ports. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832433/dynamic-ports-and-aws-applocation-load-balancer-and-ecs