# Dynamic ports and AWS Applocation Load balancer and ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs, aws-security-group

Docker containers behind ELB get dynamic ports which are auto registered with ELB so that they can get traffic redirected to them.

In order to make your web servers accessible to ELB you have to open all these ports 1024 - 65535 originating from within your security group.

Is there a way to not to have to open up a security group to a range of port but only to the pots that ELB is using?

Answer (score 7):

Security groups are never modified by AWS as this might cause conflicts and security issues. The only exception would be services such as Elastic Beanstalk. You'd likely have to do what the forum says and allow port ranges.

Per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_PortMapping.html

`The default ephemeral port range is 49153 to 65535, and this range is used for Docker versions prior to 1.6.0. For Docker version 1.6.0 and later, the Docker daemon tries to read the ephemeral port range from /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range; if this kernel parameter is unavailable, the default ephemeral port range is used. You should not attempt to specify a host port in the ephemeral port range, because these are reserved for automatic assignment. In general, ports below 32768 are outside of the ephemeral port range.`

If you actually care about what ports, you have a few options as far as I can see:

1. Not use ALB and forward ports specifically so you can specify them in the ELB security group.
2. Place the ALB in the same security group as your applications and use internal security group rules such as `TCP 0-65535` for `sg-foo` where `sg-foo` is the security group both the ALB and apps are in
3. Place the ALB in security group `sg-foo`, and put a rule on `sg-app` (where `sg-app` is the security group your applications are in) and allow traffic `TCP 0-65535` from `sg-foo` inside `sg-app`

Answer (score 2):

The EC2 host port that can be allocated as the docker published ports (dynamic ports) are ephemeral port ranges: 49153–65535 and 32768–61000 according to the document.

It looks to me they are over-wrapping (49153-61000?), but it is what the document says. Should be 32768-65535? Please someone explain why.

- [How do I set up dynamic port mapping for Amazon ECS?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/)

  > If dynamic port mapping is set up correctly, then you'll see the registered targets in the target group and the assigned port for the task. You'll also see the task in the registered targets for the following ephemeral port ranges: 49153–65535 and 32768–61000.

For instance, you can see port **32776** is allocated dynamically for a ECS task container.

```
$ sudo status ecs
ecs start/running, process 3176

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                     NAMES
6b95c013c6ba        *****.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/\ecs_monolith_myecs/xyz   "node server.js"    3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes              0.0.0.0:32776->3000/tcp   ecs_monolith_ABC-1-XYZ-feb4d68dd3d2bfad7500
dbe356e8de8c        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest                                             "/agent"            45 minutes ago      Up 45 minutes (healthy)                             ecs-agent
```

Hence we can open up 49153–65535 and 32768–61000 (or 32768-65535) for incoming traffic from the ELB targat groups which the ECS service is updating for the dynamic port mapping.

## Using Security Group (SG) of ALB

For ALB, we can limit the traffic from the SG attached to ALB. But NLB has no SG the reason of which seems to be NLB is not running on EC2, hence no SG and as ALB runs on EC2, hence with SG.

> NLB appears in your VPC as an ENI but it actually isn't. It's an extension of a component we have called HyperPlane. Whereas ALB and CLB are running on EC2 instances managed by AWS so they have "real" ENIs attached to them hence being able to use security groups.

## Using ELB IP CIDR Blocks

NLB have a static IP. However, if the target type of the target group of ELB is **instance**, then the source IP is preserved as in [Target Groups for Your Network Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html).

> If you specify targets using an instance ID, the source IP addresses of the clients are preserved and provided to your applications.
>   
>   If you specify targets by IP address, the source IP addresses are the private IP addresses of the load balancer nodes. If you need the IP addresses of the clients, enable Proxy Protocol and get the client IP addresses from the Proxy Protocol header.

If the network mode of ECS is awsvpc, then we could use IP to make sure the traffic is only from NLB, otherwise, it looks there is no way to limit the source other than using the external client IP range.

Answer (score 1):

In the container instance security group, restrict incoming traffic to a port range of 32768-65535 and the relevant subnet CIDR for your VPC and load balancer (e.g., 10.0.0.0/16).